# On retrieval from oracle value gets converted to float

Tags: oracle, pyspark

A database in oracle with column datatype as NUMBER on retrieval using pyspark gets converted to float.
eg. ID column - datatype NUMBER has value 111
On retrieval the value is shown as 111.000000

The column names are dynamic and i dont want to CAST it by hard coding. Can the data in oracle be retrieved the way it appears in the database.

I don't want the zeroes to be appended.

Comment: Read the very last reply of this Spark Issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20427

Answer (score 0):

select CAST(111.00000 AS NUMBER(38)) from dual

Comment: Cannot use it since the column names are dynamic. This is basically a part of a component that is needed to work for all queries